# Change the value of suggestive line in mahattan plot

Tags: r

I use `qqman` to generate manhattan plot, but I want to change the value of suggestive line from  -log10(1e-5)= 5 to  6.93523. The following is my code, but the line does not appear. Does anyone know how to solve it?

```
manhattan(data,col = c("cornflowerblue", "darkblue"), suggestiveline = 6.93523, cex.axis=0.6)
```

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce, but I do see the suggestive line. Except when it is outside the y-range. Do you have any -log10(P-values) above 6.93523?

Comment: can you provide more info about `suggestive line`?